# Contradiction with "cohomology group of coherent sheaf of module on projective scheme over field is finite dimensional"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, coherent-sheaves

While working on an exercise, I came up with something that seems like a contradiction and I don't seem to find out why one of my two reasoning is wrong.

Consider $X = \mathbb{P}^1_k$ and $Z = P_1\cup\ldots\cup P_n$ where $P_i$ is a closed point  of $\mathbb{P}^1_k$. I wanted to find the dimension of $H^0(X,\iota_*\mathcal{O}_Z)$ as a $k$-vector space.

From one side, I get that $H^0(X,\iota_*\mathcal{O}_Z)\cong\Gamma(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)=\mathcal{O}_{X,P_1}\oplus\ldots\oplus\mathcal{O}_{X,P_n}$. But we have that $\mathcal{O}_{X,P_i}\cong k[t]_{(t)}$ as a $k$-algebra. Sice $k[t]_{(t)}$ is infinite dimensional, so is $H^0(X,\iota_*\mathcal{O}_Z).$

From the other side, we have that $\iota$ is a proper morphism (as it is projective) and so $\iota_*\mathcal{O}_Z$ is coherent on $\mathbb{P}^1_k$. So $H^p(X,\iota_*\mathcal{O}_Z)$ is a finite dimensional vector space according to https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02O3 (similar results can be found in Hartshorne) for all $p\geq 0$.

What of this two sides is wrong ? I really can't seem to wrap my head around it...
Thanks in advance for any answer.

EDIT: $k$ is an algebraically closed scheme and $\iota:Z\rightarrow X$ is the inclusion.

Comment: You swap $Z$ to $X$ after the equals sign in your first calculation. That's your problem.

Comment: Did I ? I mean in that we do have $\Gamma(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)=\mathcal{O}_{X,P_1}\oplus\ldots\oplus\mathcal{O}_{X,P_n}$ in that case since $P_i = \mathrm{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,P_i}$ or am I wrong ?

Comment: $\Gamma(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)=\bigoplus_i\mathcal{O}_{Z,P_i}$ not $\bigoplus_i\mathcal{O}_{X,P_i}$, and of course each $\mathcal{O}_{Z,P_i}\cong k$.

Comment: But isn't $\mathcal{O}_{Z,P_i}=\mathcal{O}_{X,P_i}$ here?

Comment: No.  Regular functions on $Z$ is just the values at $P_i$, so the stalks are $k$.

Comment: I understand what you mean. It seems pretty clear.

I just don't understand one thing: It seems to me that $Z=Spec\mathcal{O}_{X,P_1}\times\ldots\times\mathcal{O}_{X,P_n}$ and so $\mathcal{O}_{Z,P_i}=\mathcal{O}_{X,P_i}$. I find since the topology on $Z$ is discrete and so $\mathcal{O}_{Z,P_i}=\mathcal{O}_Z(\{P_i\})=\mathcal{O}_{X,P_i}$.

Comment: No $Z\neq\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,P_1}\times...\times \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,P_n}$. Even if $n=1$ which I will assume now. $Z$ is a single closed point (say $Z=\{P\}$), $Z=\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{Z,P}=\operatorname{Spec} k$, but $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$ is a discrete valuation ring which has two prime ideals, so its spectrum is not a single point. The map of rings (the localization) $\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$ induces a map of spectra $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_{X,P}\to X$ but this is not a closed immersion and has actually a dense image.

Comment: Oh nice ! Thanks !